# NSStringPboardType gives xml plist not the string I want

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, copy-paste, nspasteboard

I'm trying to drag some text (a plain string) from an app.

```
NSString *text = @"My Text";
NSLog(@"%@", text);
```

I get "My Text" in the console. Then:

```
[pboard setPropertyList: text forType: NSStringPboardType];
```

If I drag this into a text editor (TextWrangler, TextEdit) I get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<string>My Text</string>
</plist>
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I just get the plain text out the other end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doing exactly what you asked it to do. It's (helpfully) creating a property list around a basic string you gave it.

You want [-setString:forType](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html):.

Comment: Indeed it is, tank you. I feel like closing this question out of embarrassment...

Comment: Others could run into the same problem so we leave our learning experiences behind to help others. Please also accept the answer that helped you so the answerers are rewarded for their effort. :-)

Comment: I did. SO wouldn't let me do it without a 6 minute wait, for whatever reason!

Comment: Heh. Thanks. Don't be embarrassed by public learning experiences. At the very least your confusion can be found by others who share it and the Q&A (with an explanation of the problem with your approach) is there to guide them.